# How do I pass a value from a container A to a container B?

Tags: java

Probably Im not explaining well. For example, I have a cup A with balls 1, 2 and 3 and a cup B with balls 4, 5 and 6. How can build the program for you to choose any ball from the cuup A and take it to the cup B.

I have understood that it would start like this:

```
int N,a[]={1,2,3}, b[]={4,5,6};
```

with N as the ball you will move.

Sorry for my bad english, thanks.

Comment: Use a `List` instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use e.g. an ArrayList, and not an int[].

Then do something like this:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomIndexA = randomGenerator.nextInt(A.size());
int elemA = A.get(randomIndexA);
```

This way you get **elemA** which is a random element from the list A.

You can do the same with list B.

Then you can move around the elements you got anyway you like.